# Why pytest fixture return generator instead of value?

Tags: pytest, yield, fixtures

Why I receive from fixture in first case Task object, and in second case generator object? And how I can fix it?

I have a fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def task():
    task = TaskFactory()
    task.add()
    yield task
    task.delete()
```

Usage:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("user_id, allow_public, expected", [
    (1, True, True)])
def test_task(user_id, allow_public, expected, task):
    assert task.is_something(user_id, allow_public) == expected
```

Work as I expected.

Now I want add arg to fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def task_with_params(is_public=False):
    def _create_task():
        task = TaskFactory(is_public=is_public)
        task.add()
        yield task
        task.delete()
    return _create_task
```

And use it like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("user_id, allow_public, expected", [
    (1, True, True),
])
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("fixture_app_with_db_scope_module")
def test_task(user_id, allow_public, expected, task_with_params):
    task = task_with_params(is_public=True)
    assert task.is_something(user_id, allow_public) == expected
```

But, instead of Task object I receive from fixture generator object and can't understand why.
I can fix it like this, but it doesn't look pythonic:

```
task = next(task_with_params(is_public=True))
```

Comment: In the second example, your fixture returns a function that yields.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand: 
I return function, which invoke with params `(is_public=True)` and must stop at 'yield task`, like in first case, why?

Comment: No, the function `_create_task` is not a fixture anymore.